# roundabout js - display only 5 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, carousel

i created a carousel with roundabout.js. i got a carousel with 10-20 li-elements. but i only want to display 5 of them. (the element what is focused, 2 prev & 2 next elements)

and second question: is there any change to set the margin between the elements? (i dont want that they overlay

ScreenShot:

[image]

My Code (i use the "teardrop" shape to get the positioneffect from the image)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slider').roundabout({
    minOpacity : 1,
    minScale : 0,
    startingChild : 2,
    shape: "tearDrop"
  });
});
```

Comment: Change minOpacity and minScale options by correct values.

Comment: yeah i tried that. but the first 5 elements should have the full opacity. and all after them should be invisible

Comment: Can you show a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you're working with?

Comment: @gn90at any solutions ??